# Pass variable from PHP to jQuery during upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using this code to automatically run my file uploading script directly on the page: 
http://pastebin.com/ZQFzk1LD

and I'm using this ajax library: http://pastebin.com/s2YmJ3BD

The thing is, everything works, but as I rename the filename during upload through the php code and I need to display it, it only shows the original filename. So let's say the rename variable in PHP is called: $rename - now I need to pass this somehow to this ajax request to grab the correct returned file within the whole ajax request. I have a few ideas, but feels like I'm too tired so early in the morning.

I appreciate all help I can get! :) Have a nice day

Comment: `I have a few ideas, but feels like I'm too tired so early in the morning.` We're not going to do all the work for you. Please post your ideas, what you've tried out so far and what did or didn't work. And please don't link to external resources (see why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question).

Comment: Could you please rephrase/restructure your question? Perhaps you can make a draft of the code you are trying to produce? I'd like to help but can not quite imagine what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this event handler:

```
...
onComplete: function(file, response){}
...
```

`response` here is something that you `echo $rename;` in PHP. I would advice you to wrap the answer into JSON with `json_encode(array('rename' => $rename));` and then in your event handler function use `response`, before using convert in back to json, from just plain-text retrieved from server by code like this:

```
function toJSON(data){
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
        data = { 'code' : -999, 'message' : 'Error while processing response' };
    }

    if (typeof data.debug != 'undefined') {
        console.log(data.debug);
    }

    return data;
}
response = toJSON(response);
```

Than you can access new name by `response.rename` in any place of `onCompete()` handler.

Also function `toJSON(data)` will output into console anything you path into `json_encode(array('debug' => 'this will be logged in console'));` which is pretty usefull.

Comment: Thank you. All I needed to do was to echo out - like you said - the $rename variable and pass it via the response parameter. Thanks!